# Running Java process from Systemd with classpath

Tags: linux, java, systemd

I have the following service:

```bsh
[Unit]
Description=App
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/opt/app
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -server /opt/app/start.ini
Restart=on-abort


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This java app requires a bunch of jars which I have to add to the classpath:

```bsh
export CLASSPATH=/opt/app/lib/*
```

My problem here is that I don't know how to automatically initialize the classpath when the service starts.

PS I am running jdk 8 on CentOS 8

Comment: This is more of a server-side question, and has more extensive answers at https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service .

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the following in your systemd file:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/app
```

And inside that file, you add the line:

```
CLASSPATH=/opt/app/lib/*
```